# Finding the cause of a stuck "Sending Data" query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, debugging, cpu

I'm running MySQL on a 1gb DigitalOcean droplet, and I have a number of scheduled tasks through the Laravel framework that run. One task in particular (seemingly) randomly causes MySQL to sit at 100% CPU, and I'm not sure where to begin in tracking down the cause.

The job downloads a JSON file containing 360 values and stores (or updates) the results in the database. Once that's done, it calls another function that gets all the results from the last 4 hours (about 240 rows) and turns it into a static image. This is run every two minutes from a cron job, and if the job fails, it retries the job up to 10 times before giving up.

According to `show processlist;`, the query is:

```
mysql> show processlist;
+-----+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id  | User  | Host      | db                  | Command | Time | State        | Info                                                        |
+-----+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 271 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    0 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 297 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    0 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 303 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    0 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 308 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    0 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 311 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    1 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 317 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Execute |    0 | Sending data | select * from `kp_minutes` where (`updated_at` = ?) limit 1 |
| 318 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Sleep   |    1 |              | NULL                                                        |
| 324 | dbusr | localhost | NULL                | Query   |    0 | starting     | show processlist                                            |
| 325 | dbusr | localhost | sample_database_com | Sleep   |    3 |              | NULL                                                        |
+-----+-------+-----------+---------------------+---------+------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In order to resolve this I have to clear any queued jobs in Laravel, then restart MySQL, and I end up doing this once or twice a day.

I've got other jobs that do similar things, but with far more data. For example one job inserts (up to) 500,000 items in the database, then pulls those values out and makes it into a static image. Those jobs run just fine, so I'm not sure why a (seemingly) simple `select` on 240 rows would cause issues.

I've tried pushing my database-heavy jobs to the end of the list in case the hundreds of thousands of rows are causing things to break. I've used Laravel's `lockForUpdate()` function to lock the `kp_minutes` rows, I've added in a delay between storing the data and generating the static image, I've read through a bunch of MySQL questions trying to find out what's going on, but I've got nothing.

How would I go about tracking down the reason for the 100% CPU, and is there anything I can do to make such "Sending data" processes time out? My MySQL install is the default that the DigitalOcean LAMP image provides, so I don't think I've messed anything up through tweaking values..

EDIT: To answer a few questions:

- The Laravel application is running on the same server as the MySQL server. I know I shouldn't do that, but it's a (hopefully interim) cost saving measure.
- Laravel's task scheduling system uses a single cron job to check for tasks to run. It then sends those tasks to a queue (e.g. Amazon SQS, or in my case, as a row in a database) where they're run. This "kp_minutes" task runs once every two minutes.
- The table in question contains about  175,000 rows, but I only select about 240 of those with the where clause
- `lockForUpdate()` uses `for update` internally: `select * from`kp_minutes`where (`updated_at`= ?) limit 1 for update`
- Running `show full processlist` gives the same results as I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you several ways to *prevent*, not *clear up*, the problem...

**Speed up the query**

Sounds like you are missing `INDEX(updated_at)`.  In particular, it is the difference between reading *one* row (due to `WHERE` and `LIMIT`) instead of reading probably most of the table (assuming they are roughly in updated order, most of 175K rows).

If that does not suffice, please provide

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE kp_minutes;
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'kp_minutes';
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;   -- using the entire query
SELECT @@version;
```

**Be careful of cron**

It sounds like you are running a job repeatedly.  Are you using `cron` or some equivalent?

Plan A:  Run the job less frequently.

Plan B:  Add code to prevent the job from running if it is already running.  It sounds like, after a few hours, you have so many copies of the job that they are simply stumbling over each other, with none of them finishing in a reasonable amount of time.

**if the job fails,...**

Why might it fail?  Fix the failures.  Even if retrying is beneficial, is **10 retries** really warranted??

**LIMIT 123000, 1000**

We can't see the entire query.  Please use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and/or find the actual SQL in the code.

If it is using a large `OFFSET`, then that is a CPU (or I/O) hog.  It must read (123000+1000) rows to satisfy the example above.  If you are using "offset", please explain.  "Remembering where you left off" is a much better way; we can discuss that.

**miscellany**

"Sending data" is bogus; it does not really give any clue of what is going on.

Laravel's tricks (lockForUpdate, etc) need to be turned into SQL for me to advise on whether they are helping or hurting.

As long as you are not swapping, don't worry about Laravel running on the same machine.  If you are swapping, decrease `innodb_buffer_pool_size` some.

Comment: I think `INDEX` was the key here. Given that I was just doing a simple `SELECT` call on what I thought was a relatively small set of info, I didn't think having an `INDEX` would do a whole lot.

Comment: @Grayda - I added to an early paragraph to address your Comment.  And added the last paragraph.